# How to add following code into Insert query in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

I Want to add this code in Insert query.............

```
 DECLARE @Upper INT;
DECLARE @Lower INT;
SET @Lower = 1   
SET @Upper = 613


DECLARE @R INT = (SELECT @Lower + CONVERT(INT, (@Upper-@Lower+1)*RAND()))  

;WITH MyTable AS (
            SELECT (ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY MyTable.SomeFiled)) as row,*
            FROM MyTable)
        SELECT * FROM rat.MLTFQuestion WHERE MyTable= @R
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Let me know by posting comments if you have any questions about my answer.  Check the mark below the upvotes if my answer helped you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A [CTE table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is just a temp table, so you can use it as such:

```
;WITH MyTable AS (
            SELECT (ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY MyTable.SomeFiled)) as row,*
            FROM MyTable)

        insert into newtable(row, col2, col3)
        SELECT row,col2,col3 FROM MyTable
```